# How to re-input a user's input in case he didn't input anything or inputted wrong?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a mastermind game as a university project. The user has to guess a number of colors with a certain order. The problem is if the user inputs something like "erd" instead of "red" his chance would be lost. I wanted to make the code somehow that it would say "invalid color!" when he inputs something invalid and let him re-enter his thing. I kinda did it but there is a small problem, look at the code below:

```
void guess(char guessBall[4][10]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cin >> guessBall[i];
    if (strcmp(guessBall[i], "red") == 0 || strcmp(guessBall[i], "blue") == 0 ||
        strcmp(guessBall[i], "green") == 0 ||
        strcmp(guessBall[i], "yellow") == 0 ||
        strcmp(guessBall[i], "white") == 0 ||
        strcmp(guessBall[i], "black") == 0) {
      continue;
    } else {
      cout << "invalid color!";
      i--;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that if the user inputs like this: `red blue WRONG black` instead of pressing enter each time, it would say "invalid color!" and let him re-enter, but the order of the colors would be wrong. example:

```
INPUT: "red WRONG green blue"
OUTPUT: Invalid Color!
INPUT: "Red"
OUTPUT: Your guess: red green blue red
```

the guess should be "red red green blue".

Would be thankful if u guys gave any suggestions.
Full code as requested:EDIT: I seemingly am unable to paste the code on my post, some parts of it get messed up and i don't know what to do. The only thing I could  think of was pasting the code on a CodePile page. here u go:https://www.codepile.net/pile/4rYRMJ93
i think codepile is a safe place ?

Comment: This isn't enough code for us to reproduce the problem. Show us a minimal version of your program so we can run it and test it for ourselves.

Comment: I uploaded the cpp file so u guys could analyze it

Comment: Show us a minimal version of your program and paste it in as an edit to your post. Nobody is going to download a file.

Comment: pasted the code on CodePile due to not being able to pasting it on my post.

Comment: Simply have the user re-enter everything. After all, in a console, you can simply press up and then change stuff. Also, you should print the words it did not understand, and maybe their position. Don't go for "the first incorrect word is changed", will cause user frustration when two words are wrong but he thinks only one is, like for "red rde green blueeuee".

Comment: I actually tried that by doing i=0; in the else statement. It DID? work but the order of the colors were all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

The `cin` will take the inputs in the order you type them. Your input example is "red WRONG green blue red".
My suggestion is that you use the debugger and put a break point a `continue` and one in the `else` statement and you can see what is going on.

My suggestion would be to make one part that handle the input and one part validating the answer. Then you can call the input function until the validation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The cin will processes the input in the order it was typed in. Since "red WRONG green blue" is typed in before the second "red," this second red is placed at the end of the input stream. Your code is probably fine, just type colors one at a time when testing your program.

Comment: Yes. It's fine when you type the colors one at a time. My question is, how can you make that way of inputting the colors work. (i.e "red WRONG green blue")

Comment: You could accept all four colors first, and check the colors in the second loop. For each incorrect color, print the error and prompt for another color using while loop, i.e. while (!validInput())) .    
I would recommend  printing the invalid color to make it more user-friendly: "Invalid color: WRONG"